# derivative of the lagrangian

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, lagrange-multiplier

The Lagrangian is defined as follows:

$$\mathcal{L}(x,\mu)=\lVert x \rVert^2_2+\underbrace{\mu^T(y-Hx)}_{**}$$
Then the derivatives of the lagrangian is taken which is what I don't understand:

$\dfrac\partial{\partial x} \mathcal{L}(x)=2x-H^T\mu$

$\dfrac\partial{\partial \mu}\mathcal{L}(x)=y-Hx$

How is the derivative of the second term ($**$) calculated both w.r.t $\mu$ and $x$?

Comment: do you know the gradient / derivative of $x\mapsto a^T x$?

Comment: Yes, and now I can understand the derivative w.r.t $\mu$: $\frac{d(\mu^T(y-Hx))}{dx}=\frac{d((y-Hx)^T\mu)}{dx}=(y-Hx)$  @user251257

Comment: sorry, I haven't understood it yet. What exactly is your question, if you know how to derive a linear function.

Comment: I know it but failed to make a relationship between what I know and what was written until your comment appeared! I still don't understand how the derivative w.r.t to x is camputed, I get $\mu^T H$ instead of $H^T\mu$

Comment: notice that $\mu^T H x = (H^T \mu)^T x$

Comment: Got it, it is clear now. Thank you @user251257

Answer (score 1):

Go from first principles and think of derivatives as linear mappings (see Cartan's *Calculus in Banach spaces*).  Let $\langle , \rangle$ be the inner product that induces the norm $|| \cdot ||$ you are using.  The term in question is then:
$$
G(x, \mu) = \langle \mu, y - Hx \rangle
$$
As a step toward computing derivatives, let's first examine the finite differences $G(x + \triangle x, \mu) - G(x, \mu)$ and $G(x, \mu + \triangle \mu)- G(x, \mu)$.
By direct computation,
$$
G(x + \triangle x, \mu) = \langle \mu, y - Hx \rangle - \langle \mu, H \triangle x \rangle,
$$
so
$$
G(x + \triangle x, \mu) - G(x, \mu) = - \langle \mu, H \triangle x \rangle.
$$
In other words, *the derivative of $G$ with respect to $x$ at $x$ is the linear mapping that sends $\triangle x$ to $- \langle \mu, H \triangle x \rangle$.*  The way to write this mapping without using the scalar product is by using transposition: $- H^{T} \mu$.

Similarly for differentiating w.r.t. $\mu$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. shouldn't it be $G(x + \triangle x, \mu) = \langle \mu, y - Hx \rangle - \langle \mu, y-H \triangle x \rangle,$?

Comment: $\langle x , z \rangle + \langle x, y \rangle = \langle x, y + z \rangle$

Comment: and? sorry I don't follow.

Comment: Evaluate the right-hand side of what you wrote $G(x, x + \triangle x)$ should be.

Comment: Right, got it. Thanks.